# .NET 7.0 VS Code namespace system not found in linux

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build a new console project. I enter `dotnet new console` and it works.

I enter `dotnet run` and it works. But VS Code (with C# extension installed) doesn't recognize it and says namespace system not found.

This goes away once I create a `globals.json` file in the project folder and set the version to 6.0. But I need to stay on the 7.0 version.

Is there any fix?

Comment: can you run a clean build ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator i googled it and i thinks its a visual studio thing so no.

Comment: can you paste more info with regards to your research

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the C# extension is installed then check the installed versions:

   ```
   dotnet --list-sdks
   dotnet --list-runtimes
   ```
2. If version 7 is not listed - install .NET 7 SDK:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
   ```
3. Explicitly pass the target framework when creating the new console app:

   ```
   dotnet new console --framework net7.0
   ```
4. Run it:

   ```
   dotnet run
   ```

If you do not see a `.vscode` folder, perform the following steps to create `launch.json` and `tasks.json`:

- Select Run > Add Configuration from the menu.
- Select .NET 5+ and .NET Core at the Select environment prompt.

Comment: i may have phrased it a bit poor but when i do `dotnet run` it runs ok and prints hello world. the problems comes from vs code.